# Form predicate from text strings c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

For example, I've got following patterns:
- **Out{d}bytes**
- **In{d}bytes**
- **In{d}bytesOut{d}bytes**
- **Out{d}words**
- **In{d}words**
- **In{d}wordsOut{d}words** where {d} is digit.

I'm not a fan of `case`.  How could I form according to this text something like:

```
p => p.Out == 8 && p.In == 16 //In8bytesOut16bytes  
p => p.Out == 8*8 && p.In == 4*8 // In8Out4words  
p => p.In == 8 // In8bytes
```

Regular expressions? Any advice will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

```
Match match;  
int inBytes = 0;  
int outBytes = 0;    
string pattern =   
@"(?<InOut>In|Out)(?<inBytes>\d+)bytes((?<Out>Out)(?     <outBytes>\d+)bytes)?";  
Func<string, IService, bool> predicate;  
match = Regex.Match(description, pattern);  
if ((match.Groups[4].Length > 0))  
{  
   int.TryParse(match.Groups[3].Value, out inBytes);  
   int.TryParse(match.Groups[5].Value, out outBytes);  
   predicate = p => p.In == inBytes && p.Out == outBytes;  
}
```

Input is formated string, which is taken from file. It should satisfy one of the mentioned patterns. The main idea is to get numbers from this string. There is a service that contains two definitions in bytes **In** and **Out** in bytes. I need to parse this string and make a condition.
For example i get In4bytesOut8bytes. I need to get 4 and 8 and make a condition
that looks like `Func<string, IService, bool> predicate = p => p.In == 4 && p.Out == 8`

Comment: A `switch` would be faster than dynamically generate lambda expressions. Also, your patterns in the first part of the question are different than the second and it's not entirely clear what `Out` and `In` and `p` refers to. Please include some code showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: What does "I'm not a fun of case" mean? Do you care for working code, or code that works and does not require you to be a fun of case?

Comment: Sorry that was **in** of course. I think that for `case` too many simple patterns, that can be done more easily. Input is string.

Comment: @Simon Belanger added code only for 3 cases In{d}bytes, In{d}bytesOut{d}Bytes and Out{d}bytes this pattern will work.

Comment: @Mike I prefer that code will work, but if it could be made simplier, why not. I agree, bad phrase "not a fun of" i mean is there way to make it better.

Comment: @user2082396 - did you mean *not a fan of*?

Comment: What is your input to this code? Is it formatted text from which you need to extract the digit, or the digit that you then need to format appropriately? Why do you not want to use `switch...case`?

Comment: @user2082396 your first two samples do not match your patterns (In8Out16bytes, In8Out4words)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky It was asked to provide what i've done so far, so that was it. I'm trying to find the appropriate solution. Only 3 cases 3 cases In{d}bytes, In{d}bytesOut{d}Bytes and Out{d}bytes, but i need all patterns to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Specification Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) instead of lambdas here:

```
public class ServiceSpecification
{
    private const int BytesInWord = 8;
    public int? In { get; private set; }
    public int? Out { get; private set; }

    public static ServiceSpecification Parse(string s)
    {
        return new ServiceSpecification {
            In = ParseBytesCount(s, "In"),
            Out = ParseBytesCount(s, "Out")
        };
    }

    private static int? ParseBytesCount(string s, string direction)
    {
        var pattern = direction + @"(\d+)(bytes|words)";
        var match = Regex.Match(s, pattern);
        if (!match.Success)
            return null;

        int value = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        return match.Groups[2].Value == "bytes" ? value : value * BytesInWord;
    }

    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(IService service)
    {
        if (In.HasValue && service.In != In.Value)
            return false;

        if (Out.HasValue && service.Out != Out.Value)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can create specifications from your input string:

```
var spec = ServiceSpecification.Parse(text);
```

And the check if any service satisfies this specification:

```
var specs = new List<ServiceSpecification>
{
    ServiceSpecification.Parse("In8bytesOut16bytes"),
    ServiceSpecification.Parse("In8wordsOut4words"),
    ServiceSpecification.Parse("In8bytes")
};

foreach(var spec in specs)
    Console.WriteLine(spec.IsSatisfiedBy(service));
```